# How to add classes to div using jquery in sequence like animation

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make animation using jQuery that simulates this GIF (I tried css3 animation keyframes but it's not neat and not nice, unless there is an easier way with css3)

[image: Animation with CSS3]

Each CSS class I'm trying to add has background color and background position

```
<div class="displayer ico1"></div>
```

The array of CSS classes are `ico1 ico2 ico3 --- ico6`. And I need to delay 3 seconds pause between each change, and of course they have to loop around back to ico1 2 3 etc

I know the `.queue()` function but I don't how to use it properly to simulate it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Edit----

I found this jQuery plugin 
https://github.com/madbook/jquery.wait

That does this trick pretty neatly !!

```
$('.displayer').addClass('ico1').wait(5000).removeClass('ico1').addClass('ico2').wait(5000).removeClass('ico2').addClass('ico3').wait(5000).removeClass('ico3').addClass('ico4').wait(5000).removeClass('ico4').addClass('ico5').wait(5000).removeClass('ico5').addClass('ico6').wait(5000).removeClass('ico6');
```

Now my only problem is to loop back to the beginning

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this code will help,

actually i am using `setInterval` function which will trigger the function after 3 second , all the classes are placed in a array

after 3 second one class is remove and other is added and this continue in a loop

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        $(document).ready(function(){   

           imageArray = new Array('icon1' , 'icon2', 'icon3', 'icon4', 'icon5', 'icon6'); //add more classes in this array
           i=0;  // first class to be used 
           setInterval(function(){
             i = (i >= imageArray.length)?0:i;
             $('.displayer').removeClass(imageArray.join(' ')).addClass(imageArray[i++]); 
           },1000); // this is the time in millisecond             
         });  
    </script>
```

`<div class="displayer"></div>`